# Replacing IN condition in Oracle

Tags: oracle, performance, update

Oracle here. I have the following tables:

```
[orders]
===
order_id : integer constraint pk_orders primary key using index
order_name : varchar2(40 char)
order_ordered_by : integer constraint fk_shoppers references accounts
order_total : number(10,2) not null
order_status : char not null

[line_items]
===
line_item_id : integer constraint pk_line_items primary key using index
order_id : integer not null constraint fk_line_items_orders references orders on delete cascade
product_id : integer not null constraint fk_line_items_products references products
line_item_quantity : integer not null

[products]
===
product_id : integer constraint pk_products primary key using index
product_name : varchar2(40 char)
product_category : varchar2(10 char)
product_available_on : date
```

I am trying to write a query that updates orders and sets their statuses to "ORDERED" where:

- the `orders.order_status` is currently "PENDING"; and
- the `products.product_category` is currently "COFFEE"; and
- the `products.product_available_on` is currently less than or equal to the present time (now)

My best attempt thus far *does* work and get the job done:

```
UPDATE orders
SET status = 'ORDERED'
WHERE order_id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT orders.order_id
    FROM orders
    INNER JOIN line_items ON line_items.orderId = orders.order_id
    INNER JOIN products ON line_items.product_id = products.product_id
    WHERE
        orders.status = 'PENDING' AND
        products.product_category = 'COFFEE' AND
        products.product_available_on <= CURRENT_DATE
);
```

Again, this *does* work, however its pretty slow so I'm trying to see if there is a way I can rewrite this to be more efficient where I'm not using the `IN` condition (I've read in several places that `IN` can cause performance issues in Oracle). Is there any way to accomplish rewriting this query without the `IN` so I can compare performance?

**Please note:** changing the tables (tweaking their fields, adding constraints/indexes/anything) is out of the realm of possibility in my particular use case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend getting rid of that DISTINCT if possible, they tend to act as "make this subquery a black box to the DB engine" keywords, which doesn't help the query optimiser make good choices.

Try the following, if it works in Oracle (I'm a MS-SQL coder, sorry)

```
UPDATE orders
SET status = 'ORDERED'
WHERE orders.status = 'PENDING'
    AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM line_items
    INNER JOIN products ON line_items.product_id = products.product_id
    WHERE
        products.product_category = 'COFFEE' AND
        products.product_available_on <= CURRENT_DATE
        AND line_items.orderId = orders.order_id 
);
```

Comment: The difference between your query and the version that Oreo posted is that your query  has a non-correlated subquery. They in part of the query and the main part of the queries are run separately and the results are joined together. Oreo's query is a correlated sub query where  the subquery is filtering the main query as the data from the main query is being gathered.

Answer (score 0):

Is this faster? This might allow the optimizer to filter by `STATUS` before touching the other tables. It also reduces the three-table join down to two.

```
UPDATE orders o
   SET orders.status = 'ORDERED'
 WHERE orders.status = 'PENDING'
   AND orders.order_id IN (
    SELECT line_items.orderId
      FROM line_items
     INNER JOIN products
        ON line_items.product_id = products.product_id
     WHERE products.product_category = 'COFFEE'
       AND products.product_available_on <= CURRENT_DATE);
```